# Unable to resume timer at the time it was stopped

Tags: javascript

I realise there are already tons of questions on this topic but no matter how much I look at the answers there I cannot make it work in my own scenario.

I'm writing a game and got a `Timer` class which counts down from 60 seconds down to 0, if it reaches 0 it should end the game.

The current problem is that when calling `stop` and then `start` again at a later time, the timer will not continue from the point it was stopped. It still checks from `this.startTime` which is when the timer first started ticking down.

So I was like alright let me re-set the `startTime` property when I call `stop` like:

```
this.startTime = this.startTime - this.elapsedTime;
```

But that gives really strange results as well, as it makes the timer jump in an incremental manner, for example 55, 45, 30, 0 when you stop/start a few more times.

How can I tweak my `stop` function to make this work?

```
class Timer {

  player;
  startTime;
  elapsedTime;
  viewableTime;
  isPaused = true;

  constructor(player) {
    this.player = player;
  }

  create() {

    this.interval = setInterval(() => {

      if (!this.isPaused && game.state.isGameActive) {

        this.elapsedTime = Date.now() - this.startTime;
        this.viewableTime = ((60000 - this.elapsedTime) / 1000).toFixed(2);

        game.view.updatePlayerTimer(this.player);

        if (this.viewableTime <= 0) {
          this.ranOut();
        }
      }
    }, 100);
  }

  start() {

    if (!this.interval) {
      this.create();
    }

    this.isPaused = false;

    if (this.startTime === undefined) {
      this.startTime = Date.now();
    }
  }

  stop() {
    this.isPaused = true;
    this.startTime = this.startTime - this.elapsedTime;
  }

  reset() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
    this.startTime = undefined;
    this.elapsedTime = undefined;
    this.viewableTime = undefined;
    this.interval = undefined;
    this.isPaused = true;
  }

  ranOut() {
    game.endGame(true);
  }
}
```

Comment: What's the point of setting `startTime` in your `stop` function? And what are you trying to set it to there?

Comment: @Ouroborus I don't know :D Since `startTime` becomes irrelevant when stopping the timer I thought I'd have to re-set it, but now I'm thinking that maybe it should be re-set when `start` is called again rather than in the `stop` function...

Comment: I think that the reason it jumps around with that change is because you should probably be adding `elapsedTime` rather than subtracting it. Regardless, resetting `startTime` in your `start` function, as you say, is usual way of doing what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to add a new class property `remainingTime`. At first, you set it as 60000. Then, in the stop() method, you subtract the elapsed time from it:

`this.remainingTime = this.remainingTime - this.elapsedTime`

In the start() method, you then need to remove the if condition, and just always reset the `startTime` to the current time, and set the `elapsedTime` to 0.

Note: make sure to also update your create() method, so it uses the new property, instead of the hard-coded value for remaining time.

Comment: Either this or simply `this.startTime = Date.now() - this.elapsedTime;` in the `start` function, but I went with your solution as it was a bit more readable :) Thanks!